# How does casting struct work?

Tags: c, casting, struct

I learn now about sockets and I saw that there is two struct
Sockaddr and sockaddrin.

The guide say to include char with 8 character in the struct  to compare one struct to another I dont understand how its work can you explain me?

Its like cast int to char[2]?

How its working with structs?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about Beej's guide to network programming?

Comment: Yes and he does no explain it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOCKADDR is a generic structure that contains an ADDRESS_FAMILY field and then 14 bytes (of type char) after that field. Depending on the value of the sin_family field (the ADDRESS_FAMILY), the 14 bytes that follow would be interpreted differently.

When the sin_family value equals AF_INET, then the SOCKADDR structure is really a SOCKADDR_IN structure, which just means that the 14 bytes really should be interpreted as:

2 bytes for sin_port
4 bytes for sin_addr
8 bytes of padding that aren't used but have to be there to make it be the same size as a SOCKADDR structure.

So if you had a pointer to SOCKADDR, and you inspected the sin_family field and it equaled AF_INET, then you could cast your pointer to a pointer to SOCKADDR_IN and access the fields that way.

Comment: First of al thank you  second its start from the top i mean the first two characterof adressfamily are reffered to  sin_port4 and so on?